# how create regex pattern for this string

Tags: regex

how create regex pattern for this string ?

```
{text@Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, venenatis leo vulputate dignissim erat, sodales wisi tempus libero sollicitudin. Ut vitae ut pretium fusce at nullam, pharetra sed suspendisse a elit sed nunc, metus scelerisque eu amet dapibus. Ipsum integer porttitor diam ultrices sed, suspendisse elit, magna nam nunc enim montes vulputate, velit nibh sed at atque quam vitae, venenatis nec justo proin. Eros non per imperdiet magna massa enim, ultricies quis iaculis tortor tempor, eleifend vel viverra ipsum vulputate consectetuer, ligula placerat sagittis, torquent nunc turpis. Neque }
```

my regex patter looks like this 
`({text@)([\n.]*)(})`

i thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Regex pattern to do __what__?

Comment: What do you want to catch/how do you want to validate your string?

Comment: i search all characters between @ character and } character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to catch the text after `text@`, inside `{...}`, you can use (given that there are no `}` in your wanted text):

```
{text@([^}]*)}
```

The result will be in the first capturing group: http://regex101.com/r/oP5tT2

`[^}]` means any character *except* a `}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea :

```
{text@([\w\s,.]+)}
```

The text in brackets and after `text@` will be captured in the first capturing group.

Comment: Nope, `.` is not a special character inside a character class.